# Swiper JS Thumbs - When clicking on the thumb the main slider transitions/scrolls through all main slides instead of just loading the selected thumb

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I have a Swiper setup with the thumbs property. Everything works fine but I would upon selecting a thumbnail the main slider to just load the selected thumbnail without transitioning/scrolling through all slides between the active one and the selected one.

I would essentially want to achieve the transition effect if I would be clicking on the very next or previous slide to the currently selected one(without the scrolling effect for all slides in between on the main slider).

This is my swiper below:

```
swiperGallery = new Swiper('.swiper-slider-' + index, {
                direction: 'horizontal',
                loop: false,
                freeMode: freeMode,
                spaceBetween: spaceBetween,
                scrollbar: {
                    el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
                    draggable: true
                },
                breakpoints: {
                    1440: {
                        slidesPerView: getLargeDesktopSlidesCount($this),
                        grid: {
                            rows: getLargeDesktopRows($this),
                            fill: "row"
                        },
                        spaceBetween: spaceBetween
                    },
                    1232: {
                        slidesPerView: getSmallDesktopMaxSlidesCount($this),
                        grid: {
                            rows: getSmallDesktopMaxRows($this),
                            fill: "row"
                        },
                        spaceBetween: spaceBetween
                    },
                    1024: {
                        slidesPerView: numberOfSlidePerRow,
                        grid: {
                            rows: gridRows,
                            fill: "row"
                        },
                        spaceBetween: spaceBetween
                    },
                    812: {
                        slidesPerView: getMaxTabletSlidesCount($this),
                        grid: {
                            rows: getMaxTabletRows($this),
                            fill: "row"
                        },
                        spaceBetween: spaceBetween
                    },
                    600: {
                        slidesPerView: getMinTabletSlidesCount($this),
                        grid: {
                            rows: getMinTabletRows($this),
                            fill: "row"
                        },
                        spaceBetween: spaceBetween
                    },
                    460: {
                        slidesPerView: 4,
                        grid: {
                            rows: 3,
                            fill: "row"
                        },
                        spaceBetween: spaceBetween
                    },
                    320: {
                        slidesPerView: 2,
                        grid: {
                            rows: 6,
                            fill: "row"
                        },
                        spaceBetween: spaceBetween
                    }
                }
            });

            var swiper2 = new Swiper(".main-swiper-@mainSwiperGuid", {
                spaceBetween: 10,
                navigation: {
                    nextEl: ".next-@nextGuid",
                    prevEl: ".prev-@prevGuid",
                },
                thumbs: {
                    swiper: swiperGallery,
                },
            });
        });
```

I tried setting the slideToClickedSlide property to false but that didn't work.

Comment: `No way` to solve this by thumbs API **beside set speed to 0 (But than you destroy the swipe animation) -or- change effect from slide to fade. SUM: This is expected behavior (Looks fine in my opinion). This is more an Feature request under swiper Github Repo. https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues

Comment: Thanks for confirming that! It looks great, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @ezra-siton in the comments, switching the "effect" param to "fade" achieved my desired behavior.

https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#fade-effect